How to stream Azure keyvault events to event grid via logic app and vnet integration?
I'm struggling to figure out the best way to achieve the following use case:
I want to be able to rotate an Azure SPN secret and store it in Key Vault. I've created a Logic App flow that is triggered via Event Grid and Everything is working perfectly, but if I want to implement it in a hardened environment where all of the Azure services are enforced with private endpoints, it slows me down, due to the fact that EventGrid doesn't  have any vNET integration.
I have a Logic App with a private endpoint and a Key Vault with a private endpoint. The Event Grid reaches the Logic App via an HTTP call. I guess I can use APIM with Application Gateway on top? any other smart way?
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,


I have a Logic App with a private endpoint and a Key Vault with a private endpoint. The Event Grid reaches the Logic App via an HTTP call. I guess I can use APIM with Application Gateway on top? any other smart way?

I do agree and I feel you are in right direction that you can use APIM with Application gateway.
Alternatively as you have said you can use below triggers , To send the event to Logic app, you can simply use azure event grid trigger as below:

And now you can store it as secret/keys in keyvault.
If you want to send/ publish, you can use  Publish Event action, to send data, type to event:


Thanks @RithwikBojja, but in this case - the event grid will still needs to be able reaching the logic app. the thing here that Microsoft is doing, when you enable private endpoint on storage account, logic app, etc. you are blocking the public traffic, thus the event grid will need to have some vnet integration is some way in order to reach out to internal logic app.

Yes, that's true , you have to have vnet integration on all services you want to integrate with vnet integarted logic app

Even in Event Grid you can enable Private End Point connection https://i.imgur.com/2rmp8V5.png

Basically, I'm using system topic with event subscription which doesn't have vnet integration capability in order to reach logic app service. I'm currently checking an option with existing firewall appliance (which is publicly exposed) and from there i can point into logic app via internal leg.

Oh fine, you can do that
